# Mongodb geospatial query performance

Tags: mongodb

I am writing a nodejs app involving geocodes ( ~50million places) stored in mongodb (using mongo native driver). For development I am testing with sample data (airports of the world ~45k locations http://www.ourairports.com/data/airports.csv ). I am following GeoJSON format and building 2dsphere index on location field(named "geometry"). Then I am doing a $geowithin query to find locations.

Evrything works as expected. The issue is that when I am querying for a polygon containing US, the query is taking around 4-6sec for returning 22845 locations.

`db. airports.ensureIndex({ geometry: '2dsphere' })`

`db.airports.find({ geometry: { '$geoWithin': { '$geometry': { type: 'Polygon', coordinates: [ [ [ -127.32917843921399, 75.11297289119061 ], [ -71.32126356078601, 75.11297289119061 ], [ -71.32126356078601, 12.305525108809391 ], [ -127.32917843921399, 12.305525108809391 ], [ -127.32917843921399, 75.11297289119061 ] ] ] } } } })`

I am sure that this cant be correct. This way I cant imagine response times with 50million points.
Would appreciate if someone can point me in direction to improve the performance of this.

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue?
I am hesitating between different geospatial solutions (mostly MongoDB and PostGIS)